# Hot keys to avoid

Tags: hotkeys, web-standards

I want to add a hot key that can be used **while an input has focus** and will be used to toggle a search result.

I guess this question has been more generalized in that I would like to know which hotkeys to avoid so as to not conflict with anything. I found this [list of hotkeys](http://www.disabled-world.com/assistivedevices/computer/hotkeys.php), but I doubt there is a complete list anywhere. So from looking over that list, I guess I would avoid the following:

- Function Keys: F1, F3, F5, F11, F12
- Navigation: Tab, arrows, home, end, pageup/down, home, end, insert, delete, numpad
- Ctrl + (a, c, d, f, h, j, n, o, p, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, z)
- Alt + function keys - too easy to slip and hit alt-F4
- Alt + Navigation - browser history, change tabs/windows, etc.
- Alt + letters - windows menu (alt-F = file, etc)
- Shift + Navigation - selects text inside of inputs
- Caps lock (unless you're evil LOL)
- Window/Meta key
- I don't want to use multi-key combos like ctrl-alt, ctrl-shift, ctrl-alt-shift, etc.

So, that leaves:

- Unused function keys
- Shift + function keys
- Ctrl + left over letters
- Alt + letter keys (but make sure they aren't in the menu)

Are there any other key combinations that should be avoided that I just don't know about?

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look at this (searchable) Wikipedia page on cross-platform keyboard shortcuts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts Each of these keys should certainly be avoided in the toggle functionality.